# Copy cells next to each other to another work sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that is labelled SCHEDULE. In column `G`, I have set up a drop-down list of user names (first and last). In column `H`, I have their mobile contact numbers. On a second sheet labelled CONTACT LIST, I have user names and contact numbers in two cells.

I want to get the mobile number to auto-generate when I pick someone from the drop-down list on the SCHEDULE sheet.

The contact list only has one user name and number,
for example:

```
Cell C20 "Joe Smith" Cell D20 "1234567890", 
Cell C21 "Jane Smith" Cell D21 "0987654321"
```

On my SCHEDULE sheet, they may appear dozens of times, tired of inputting their numbers each time!

I assume an `IF()` or `VLOOKUP()` might work, just can't get any to work at the moment.

Comment: Hi, you're right that an If or Vlookup might work ..... you say you "just can't get any to work at the moment" - can you show us what attempts you have made?  That will help others to assist you with where you might be going astray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic situation where you can use a simple `VLOOKUP()`.

I assume your name/number data is stored in the range `C1:D21` on the sheet "CONTACT LIST" and in cell `G1` on sheet "SCHEDULE" you have set-up the drop-down list.

Then you can simply put in cell `H1` the following `VLOOKUP()` formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,'CONTACT LIST'!$C$1:$D$21,2,FALSE)
```

Thus, your lookup value is in `G1`, which is the name. The name is lookedup in your contact list and you return the second column (the number). You also want to make sure that you do an exact match search.

To re-use the function multiple times just copy it to the corresponding cells and ensure that lookup value corresponds to what you wanna lookup in "CONTACT LIST".

Comment: thanks heaps, exactly what I was trying to do.
also added in an iferror to remove the NA errors to make it nice and tidy.

thank you very much, appreciate the assistance greatly.